# Is this a spam track on Spotify?

Tags: music-business, spotify, quality

Recently, Spotify included a track in my Discover Weekly playlist that has left me puzzled:

[Häx – Divin temo, The Dø](https://open.spotify.com/track/6Ren99RnDav1xypx2AVIzj?si=a96f2de2d16c4950)

I'm a fan of [The Dø](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_D%C3%B8), which I assume triggered the algorithm to recommend this track. However, I've never heard of Divin temo before.

Upon listening to the track for a few seconds, it became apparent that The Dø had nothing to do with this music. Further listening only reinforced my impression that this isn't a traditional song but rather sounds like someone messing around in GarageBand.

I have a broad taste in music and respect different styles, acknowledging that musical taste is highly subjective. No offense meant to Divin temo, but I struggle to understand if this track genuinely appeals to listeners.

**My Questions**

1. Do people actually listen to this type of music? If so, what genre does it belong to, and can you recommend similar tracks or artists?
2. Could this be considered spam? If it is, how did it end up on Spotify, and why would someone release a “spam” track?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/indieheads/comments/vs29b4/i_took_a_deep_dive_into_a_strange_spotify_scam/) where someone points out that there are "artists" that found a way to upload songs to Spotify that seemingly are collaborations with well-established artists. These songs have started popping up on the Release Radars of Spotify users, allowing them to gain a lot of plays, free advertising, or even [a lot of revenue](https://www.mukken.com/m/en/the-spotify-scam-this-is-how-criminals-made-millions-with-spotify/).

The song you link to probably followed the same process. What's more, the link to the artist they pretend to have collaborated with has already been severed from the actual The Dø, so Spotify must have caught up to them. This is definitely spam.

My suggestion: go the "artist" page, and flag them.

> Do people actually listen to this type of music? If so, what genre does it belong to, and can you recommend similar tracks or artists?

- I guess many, if not most, Spotify users will listen to whatever's thrown at them—at least for a while. One would also expect Spotify to play similar music, so there's always the initial benefit of the doubt.
- As for the genre of this song: I'm not going to give it another partial listen, and I think it doesn't matter. As far as I remember it, it sounded like something thrown together in a DAW; a simple looped custom melody set to a VSTi over pre-existing instrumental soundpool loops, with some vague (and badly recorded?) singing in the background. Maybe 'eclecticism' comes closest :)

---

Another indication of the nature of this "artist" was the album cover:

[image]

This is obviously AI-generated (look at the hands—once you see the highly deformed anatomy, it becomes obvious in all the weird curves of the arms), and it's not a particularly interesting image of an ersatz artist, and not album or single artwork, pointing to a low-effort, and therefore likely spam- or trolling-related "artist".